# Jquery load in image dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

When my page loads I have an empty image, after a user inputs the correct query string I parse it and return the id/location of the image using AJAX.

```
<a class="bigImg rght" style="width:258px;">
<img src="" alt="Slide" width="298" height="224" /></a>
```

Then I append the new id's into the img src field, but what it is not doing is loading the new image in.

```
parent_img.attr("src","http://www.mysite.com/files/"
+(data.offset_num)+"/"+(data.offset_id)).fadeIn(1000);
```

So now my html looks like this:

```
<a class="bigImg rght" style="width:258px;">
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/files/4823413/008234" alt="Slide" width="298" height="224" /></a>
```

which is the correct location, but it's not refreshing the image, 
**how can I force it to do so? so the new image is loaded in.**

Comment: are you sure that's the right location? That URL is a 404

Comment: the URL is correct I just changed it to not use the actual url of my site.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bj4SJ/

Comment: @johnKoerner I forgot to add in the img extension :(

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this by tacking a random ID onto the end of the image.

```
var img_src = '/images/path_to_image.jpg?' + new Date().getTime();
$('#img_id').attr('src', img_src);
```

Comment: This will force the browser to reload the image everytime. Have you tried creating your image element with jquery and then adding it to your document ?

Comment: he wants the image to refresh every time, so this will do what he wants. his image tag exists, with no src. by setting the src the way i have posted, it would change it and load the image correctly.